# How loopback hooks work flow happens internally

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am new to **loopback**, I was surprised when I seen hooks(Remote,observe and model) in loopback.

I want to know which hook trigger first If I use all the hooks.I have tried this code snippet. But I didn't get which hook is trigger first.

```
Users.beforeRemote('create', (ctx, modelInstance, next) => signup(ctx, modelInstance, next, Users));

Users.observe('before save', validateBeforeSave);

Users.beforeSave = testFunction
```

can anyone explain.

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel your problem is solved. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @Overdrivr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Users.beforeRemote('create', ..)` is called first, because it is called before `Users.create` as its name indicate

(In loopback, a remote is a model's function that can be called remotely, using the REST API for instance. When you make a `POST api/Users` you actually make a **remote** call to `Users.create`)

Then the remote method `Users.create` is called. At some point inside this method, the data will be persisted to the database (= save). So just before the data is saved, `Users.observe('before save',..)` is called.

Finally, `Users.beforeSave` is a model hook, and would be called at the same moment than `Users.observe('before save',..)`.

**Note**: `Users.beforeSave` and most model hook [are deprecated](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) in favor of operation hooks.

To summarize

1. `Users.beforeRemote('create', ..)`
2. `Users.create`
3. `Users.observe('before save',..)`
4. etc.

And don't use `Model.beforeSave`.